# Set UltraGrid to ReadOnly property, vb.net

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, infragistics, readonly, ultrawingrid

In my project, I have a form that has 3 radio buttons, an ultragrid, and a textbox. When I load the form, I want the ultragrid to be `ReadOnly`, or the equivalent of this, and then I want it to become active again when `rbCategory` is checked (one of the radiobuttons). I then need it to be set to `ReadOnly` again if one of the other 2 radio buttons are selected.

I feel like `ReadOnly` is not a property that can be used with Ultragrids, so what is the equivalent (to make it grey, like a `ReadOnly` textbox, basically), and how is this coded?

I tried using

```
ugCategories.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowUpdate = DefaultableBoolean.False
```

but this didn't seem to do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting AllowUpdate you are actually making the grid read-only. If you need to change the grid appearance you need to set appearance for the read-only cells like this:

```
ugCategories.DisplayLayout.Override.ReadOnlyCellAppearance.BackColor = Color.Gray;
```

Further, you may consider set and the CellClickAction to CellSelect like this:

```
ugCategories.DisplayLayout.Override.CellClickAction = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellClickAction.CellSelect;
```

You may also check [this](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/23089.aspx) article for more helpful information from Mike Saltzman - Infragistics Win Forms Guru